# Diagonalization of a Matrix and $\lambda I -A$ Rank

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-rank

Let $$A = \left(\begin{matrix} -1 & 3 & -1 \\-3 & 5 & -1 \\ -3 & 3 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$$ be a matrix.

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is:

$$(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda-1)$$

According to my professor's notes, since $\lambda=2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and the fact that:

$$\text{rank}(2I-A)=\text{rank}\left(\begin{matrix} 3 & -3 & 1 \\3 & -3 & 1 \\ 3 & -3 & 1\end{matrix}\right)=1$$ the matrix is diagonalizable.

However, I can't understand why.

What is the connection between the rank of $(\lambda I-A)$ and matrix diagonalization?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: My advice when it goes to theory is to forget a bit about the characteristic polynomial and read a bit more about the minimal polynomial :)

Comment: Seems reasonable, I'll do it next time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An $n \times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if(f) we can find $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.  In particular, this is equivalent to saying that for each eigenvector $\lambda$, we have a number of eigenvalues equal to the algebraic multiplicity of that eigenvalue (i.e. the associated exponent in the characteristic polynomial).

Because the rank of $A - 2I$ is $1$, the rank-nullity theorem tells us that the nullity is $2$, which means that there are $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 2$.  Since $1$ is an eigenvalue, we have an eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 1$.  So, in total, we have $3$ linearly independent eigenvectors.  So, $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was brief and clear.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom , how can we tell that the eigenvectors associated to $\lambda=2$ are linearly independent to the one associated to $\lambda=1$ ? This is not a criticism, I just can not recall how this is justified.

Comment: @Svetoslav it is a theorem that this will always be the case.  You should try to prove it for yourself, or ask about it in a post.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I recalled it :)

Comment: Actually the fact that the nullity is 2 for $A-2I$ does not mean there exist two independent eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

An $n \times n$ matrix is diagonalizable iff the dimensions of its eigenspaces sums to $n$. The eigenspace of  the eigenvector $\lambda=2$ is spanned by vectors $x$ such that $Ax=2x$ and this means that $(A-2I)x=0$, so the space of the eigenvectors has the same dimension as the kernel of $A-2I$, and since this dimension is $2$, and the dimension of the eigenspace of $\lambda=2$ has dimension $1$, A is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the rank is 1, you are able to have a free family of 2 $\lambda$-eigenvectors, which is a good start to find an eigenvector base (length 3). A in such a base would be a diagonal matrix

Answer (score 0):

**Important Observation**

That two eigenvalues are the same could mean we have either one or two eigenvectors.

For instance the matrix 
$${\bf A} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{array}\right]$$

has one eigenvector $[1,0]^T$, but two eigenvalues "1". The space corresponding to this eigenvalue is a *generalized eigenspace*, which has one true eigenvector and other vectors which are not true eigenvectors but map up "towards" the true one.

Comment: Note that, in this case, the nullity of $A - I$ is $1$. So, we only have $1$ linearly independent eigenvector.